# Rails 3 Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Property model with some basic content like Property Description, Property Title, etc.

The type of the property can be a house, villa, castle, B&B, etc. What is the best way to implement the property type? For example I want to generate top 10 listing of property types X on different pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities. If these types are static you can declare a constant in the Model like this:

```
PROPERTY_TYPES = %w[villa, castle, other]
```

And add it to the view like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :property_type, Model::PROPERTY_TYPES, :to_s, :humanize %>
```

But if you want something dynamic you should add another Model which contains the different types possible. ANd you should also avoid using the name `type`as field name because its used by ActiveRecords.